Querying the Goods Sold to update the Inventory Management sheet
Hello brilliant minds,
I have two sheets Goods Sold and Inventory management that I am struggling to connect as they are interrelated.
The idea is to query the Goods Sold in terms of quantity to Inventory Management under the sheet Input Master.
So I am imagining two ways,
First, Aggregate/Sum all the Quantities sold (Goods Sold) on a particular day and get the input marked as "Out" in the "Inventory In&Out sheet" per product with date and Quantity under the Qty Column.( I have already tried this but breaks constantly with the error: In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.)
Second, any way if I could be to get each record of the Quantity Sold get recorded one by one as "Out" as it happens. (maybe not very lean)
I have tried to do something under "Inventory In&Out" Sheet but it works for a bit and breaks after an hour or so. I am super open to new ideas.
Link to sheets:
Goods Sold: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/138y2wODj9WAnsycQy6yknQc0mEdLxZqGUFjwVZ6BEjo/edit?usp=sharing
Inventory Management: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N47aeu3rbtEFA9k7BYR2EQ2x3EComMFHkrlU5NgkE2I/edit?usp=sharing
A super big thank you in advance!
:)

Can you recreate this error scenario & then manually add your ideal expected output aside so that we can get a clear picture on what is it that you are looking to fix/update?!

Sure, thank you for replying.
Lets ignore my solution and the error, could I ask you to suggest something to achieve the desired results please?

@rockinfreakshow - It is very hard to recreate the error scenario. So here is the screenshot attached, I did not do anything and the formula broke.
I am looking to use the two sheets to update the inventory "in" and "out". So, for example, the inventory out record is created in the "Good Sold - SO", which should be queried in the "Inventory Management System - SO" under the sheet "Inventory In&Out". Screenshot -https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QTP9AHAVc4uJ_vzkZ7UZROcYrZ8FT5S9/view?usp=sharing

Also, I have to manually input the inventory that is coming in, in the same workbook under "Input Master".
Now, if you check the "I Summary" worksheet, we make sales everyday and the inventory out is listed under col "out", whenever we have the stocks come in, it appears under col "in". The col "Opening balance" is basically the inventory left prior to current day and the col "closing bal" is the sum of remaining inventory on the current day after all the sales.
Current solution breaks, could you please help me and suggest something that works just fine? @rockinfreakshow
Thanks!

the error message could mean that one or more queries you are stacking using the flower brackets {} has no output. Use vstack instead of {} to avoid the array_literal error. Here's one Q&A which explains how to deal with this specific scenario

@rockinfreakshow, thank you again for the help but I am still struggling. I applied the formula in the column G but there is an "Formula Parse ERROR". I checked the thread, no luck. Could you please help me look into it as I have never worked with vstack please.
thanks
